# Hello! Are there any liberal Christians here?

Tags: discussion

I have [a question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/26087/is-there-a-need-for-christians-to-believe-in-christianity-at-all-if-they-dont) directed at liberal Christians who don't believe in resurrection. And then my question is closed because "liberal Christians" is a not well-defined terminology. I don't want to start another question "*whether "liberal Christians" is well-defined or not*", so I just hope that

1. the mods will reopen the question
2. a liberal Christian will answer it

That's it! Thanks

PS: No, this is not a question but more of a plea to get some sanity out of this site.

Comment: did the question got reopened?

Comment: Maybe you should read the "Brothers, we are not Christians" meta post. Caleb is a Christian. You say you are. But we are not. Therefore, anybody - even a committed atheist - can contribute to this website, as long as the answers are sufficiently supported by evidence from credible sources like academic journals and official denominational records. You may want to look into *liberal theology* yourself. :)

Comment: This is what made it on-topic: "on what basis do extreme liberal Christians identify themselves as Christians?" compounded with you defining 'extreme liberal Christian' as one who believes really none of the doctrines but identifies as Christian anyway.

Comment: @graviton do L.C. believe in hell?

Comment: @AaronKorn, in my definition, they don't. Or even if they do, the Hell they believe is very different from the traditional Christian view of hell ( fire, permanent torture etc)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is now reopened, so point 1 is done! We are still waiting on point 2.

I self-identify as liberal - though I *do* believe in the resurrection and hence I'm not "extreme liberal" by your question's definition. There are probably more people here than you think who have liberalish views, on some axis or another. My impression of our more conservative users, by the way, is:

1. We don't have a lot of presence from "extreme conservatives" (whatever that means - but I think the conservative opposite to "extreme liberals" would be much less mainstream than the conservatives I see here).
2. They are decent folk who are as scrupulous as anyone when it comes to maintaining the site standards, voting on the basis of quality rather than agreement with content, and treating people with respect.

This is based on over two years of being here, and accruing over 11k points of reputation while publicly identifying as liberal and generally answering from that standpoint on questions where it applies.

It's true we have occasional problems, but somehow we muddle through. For your question, I see that there's been discussion in comments, editing of the question to make the scope more obvious, and clearing out of answers that didn't fit. I hope that you *will* get a useful answer to your question (currently at +3 net votes, which is good!) and that you'll stay around to ask and answer more good questions.

Answer (score 4):

Liberal is not a very helpful term, as it tends to have no clear meaning, often only referring to someone who I deem to be less conservative than [some subjective standard]. See the problem? It's the same problem with the word 'fundamentalist' (i.e. someone who takes something more seriously than [some subjective standard]). Even 'conservative' isn't all that helpful, as there is again a subjective standard of measurement. It is best to clearly define what you mean, i.e. "Those who identify as Christians yet do not believe in [specific things]."

**See my post: [Liberal vs. Conservative: An Unhelpful Spectrum](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3649)**

Comment: Also because it has different meanings. Liberal in European theology (as opposed to US theology) generally means specifically the school of theology that developed following the philosophy of the Enlightenment, e.g. Schleiermacher. There it isn't even opposed to "conservative".

Comment: @lonesomeday BUT it is a well-defined and non-subjective definition referring to a specific group.  Fair point about it being ambiguous as all get out, though.