# Are there any "Church of the East" and/or Oriental Orthodox members here?

Tags: discussion

Hopefully demographics questions like this aren't off topic for meta. (I see there is a precedent question [here](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3509/hello-are-there-any-liberal-christians-here))

I'm just curious if any of our members are from the Oriental Orthodox Church or the Church of the East? I've been curious about these groups ever since I found out about them. I haven't got any specific questions I'd like to ask but I'm just "curious in general" about them. I'd love to attend their liturgies some time, particularly the Ethiopian Orthodox liturgy, which I hear is quite unique. I'm also fascinated by how the Ethiopian Orthodox biblical canon is absolutely massive and would like to read those scriptures for myself some day

Answer (score 3):

We definitely have had several Oriental Orthodox members previously, though I don't know how many are very active now. I'm not sure if we've had any Ethiopian Orthodox members. But you can always ask questions, you might just have to wait to get an answer.